# Editing 'expression' used in creating Field with 'field calculator'

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I have created a new field 'COROAD' using field calculator and now I want to edit the expression. I cannot find a way to view the expression and edit it.

Answer (score 2):

if your field is a normal field, choose "Update existing Field" and have a look under "Recent (fieldcalc)"

[image]

else if your field is a virtual field, go through layer properties > Fields and there you can edit the expression of the virtual field definition:

[image]